Order of operations when calculating $\cos kx$ and $\cos k(x-a)$
It’s a long long time since I did any maths…. I need to know how to interpret the formulas in a textbook entitled “Roark's Formulas for Stress and Strain”.
Specifically, the formulas in TABLE 8.8 for Shear, moment, slope, and deflection formulas for beams under simultaneous axial compression and transverse loading.

Re: formula F1  which is  $\cos kx$
Do I ...

multiply $k\cdot x$, and then find the $\cos$ of this product?

OR

find the $\cos$ of $k$ and then multiply this by $x$?


Re formula Fa1, which is $(x-a)^0 \cos k(x-a)$
Do I ..

subtract $a$ from $x$, then multiply this difference by the $\cos$ of $k$?

OR

subtract $a$ from $x$, then multiply this difference by $k$, and then find the $\cos$ of this product?


Many many thanks

Please use MathJax for math formatting

In general, the convention is that $\cos kx$ means $\cos(kx)$ and $\cos k(x-a) = \cos(k(x-a))$. To write "the cosine of $k$, then multiply by $x$ would be more likely $(\cos k) x$.

Even more likely $x \cos k$ if the multiplication by $x$ is supposed to come after the cosine.

The order of operations inside a trigonometric function follow the PEDMAS (parenthesis, exponents, division/multiplication, addition/subtraction) evaluation rules.  Thus, for $\cos (kx)$ for formula F1, you would find $kx$ first then take the cosine in formula F1; similarly, you would find the quantity $k(x-a)$ first and then take the cosine for $\cos (k(x-a))$ for formula Fa1.
To eliminate confusion, the best convention is to put the constant/non-trigonometric functions in parentheses.  This way, $\cos (kx)$ is clear you're taking the cosine of $kx$, whereas $\cos kx$ may cause confusion (is it $\cos kx$ or $\cos k \cdot x$?)
Parentheses can also be used for powers of trigonometric functions (e.g. $\cos^2(4x)$), inverse trigonometric functions (e.g. $\arccos (\pi/4)$), hyperbolic functions (e.g. $\tanh (\ln x)$ and $\text {arsech } (2x)$), and natural and common logarithms (e.g. $\ln (e^{xt})$ and $\log_{10} (70)$)  because it highlights what quantity is evaluated by that function.
